# How do you return the data from an AJAX success event to the outer function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want the check_membership() function below to return the AJAX "data".
However, "result" keeps getting set to the XHR object, not the returned JSON object.

How do I fix this?

```
function check_membership() {

    var result;

    result = jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/member',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            return data;
        }
    });

    return result;
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the "return data" statement does not work as one would expect. So, I changed this line to "result = data" and things work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript will not 'wait' for the $.ajax's success callback to fire before returning from the main function, so there's a good chance that nothing will be returned. You will have to either use a synchronous-Jax call by setting the `async` option to `false` (which will block the browser for the duration of the request) or revise your strategy, e.g. by doing what you want to ultimately get done *within* the success callback. For example:

```
function update_membership_status() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/member',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $("#status").text('Signed In:' + json.SignedIn + "  msg" + json.msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still doesn't work. Would you please take a look at my updated code above? "Result" is still set to the XHR object, not the returned JSON object.

Comment: I figured it out. See my comment above. It looks like returning data from within a callback does not behave as one would expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = 
{
   ajax: function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/member',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
                return data.signedIn;
        }
     });
   }  
}
```

then call result.ajax(); by whatever

Answer (score 0):

You can use **async** property to return data synchronously:

```
function check_membership() {
  var result = jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/member',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false
    });
 return result.SignedIn;
}
```

Comment: I put the alert function in there for debugging purposes. 
I just want check_membership() to return the AJAX "data".

Comment: oh sorry it was not clear enough. i've explained another solution in updated post. check this one.

Comment: I added "async: false" (see updated code above) and still same result.